# Why is WebDriverJS asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webdriver

Most of the Selenium bindings are synchronous (Java, .Net, Python), but JS binding was some why made async. Why? What are the benefits?

I see one benefit - most of the code (not the one inside of promises) is checked quickly for errors in syntax. But in the same time - it's pretty complicated to debug that code. I'm on the fence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I got to is that NodeJS is asynchronous in its nature - it has one working thread and multiple IO threads. If an HTTP request is sent (which is an IO), the main thread stops when it gets to the IO itself and then it gives away the IO work to other threads. Then when response is coming back another IO thread invokes the main thread.

Since this is how NodeJS naturally works it was the easiest to implement webdriver-js in this manner.